# Прошу помощи с пониманием single responsibility principle на примере метода и класса

Tags: c#

1. Есть метод, который возвращает лист с именами csv файлов, найденных в папке с программой:

   ```
    public static List<string> GetListOfTables()
    {
        var tables = new List<string>();

        do
        {
            tables = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.csv").Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file)).ToList();

            if (tables.Count == 0)
            {
                Output.Invoke("\nNo .csv files are found, " +
                    "please put a table csv file in the program folder and press <Enter> to continue");

                while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { }
            }
        }
        while (tables.Count == 0);

        return tables;
    }
   ```

В нем встроенна валидация (вместо исключения), что если файлов не найдено, юзеру нужно скопировать файл в папку и нажать на клавишу.

У данного метода единственная отвественность (в итоге возвращает лист, а проверка - это всего лишь проверка) или множественная (возвращает лист и проверяет корректность действий пользователя)?

Ведь можно создать отдельный метод **ValidationCsvFiles** с блоком проверки и затем включить или делегировать его в основной метод?

2. Есть класс, который возвращает лист с данными из конкретного файла

```
static class CsvParser
    {
        public static List<string> GetListOfTables() { }

        public static List<List<object>> GetTable(string tableName) { }
    }
```

У данного класса единственная ответственность (в итоге возвращает лист с данными, а лист со списком файлов - это вспомогательный инструмент) или множественная (возвращает лист с данными и лист с файлами)

Ведь лист с файлами можно реализовать в другом классе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В книге "Чистая Архитектура ..." Роберт Мартин утверждает что традиционно принцип единственной ответственности описывается так:

> Модуль должен иметь одну и только одну причину для изменения
>
> Программное обеспечение изменяется для удовлетворения нужд
> пользователей и заинтересованных лиц. Пользователи и заинтересованные
> лица как раз и есть та самая "причина для изменения", о которой
> говорит принцип. Фактически принцип можно перефразировать так:
>
> Модуль должен отвечать за одного и только за одного пользователя или
> заинтересованное лицо.

Стоит сразу оговориться что пользователь это не "ну такая тетенька которая ...". Чтобы не раздувать ответ переписыванием всей главы, рекомендую приобрести книгу и прочитать дальнейшие пояснения что подразумевается под пользователем (или актором) и модулем в данном случае.

Признаки нарушения принципа единственной ответственности по Мартину:

- Непреднамеренное дублирование. Например, класс имеет несколько методов, в которых используются похожие фрагменты кода. Можно эти фрагменты привести к общему виду и вынести в отдельный метод, чтобы избежать дублирования. Но с другой стороны, теперь стало труднее вносить изменения в один из методов, не затрагивая другие. Это признак того, что класс **возможно** нарушает принцип единственной ответственности. Нарушает или нет, зависит от того используются ли эти методы одним актором или многими.
- Конфликты при слиянии рабочих веток в Git. Обычно в команде каждый человек работает над своей задачей (если конечно команда не практикует парное программирование). Если изменения двух программистов затрагивают один и тот же файл, то может возникнуть необходимость разрешать конфликты при слиянии веток. Это тоже признак того, что **возможно** нарушается принцип единственной ответственности.

Подытожим: принцип единственной ответственности не о том, можно ли или нет разбить модуль на еще более мелкие модули, отвечающие за еще более узкую область. Такое дробление не всегда улучшает код, а порой приводит к смешным последствиям. Таким как эта нашумевшая история: [NPM и left-pad: мы разучились программировать?](https://habr.com/ru/post/280099/).

Принцип единственной ответственности о том, как избежать трудностей при изменении кода в будущем.

Comment: Не очень понял, как ссылка на проблему с пакетами связана с SRE?

Comment: SRP конечно имел ввиду

Comment: @tym32167, никак не связана. ссылка была дана в контексте "минуты ворчания" на приверженцев дробить модули до атомов.

Comment: Внес небольшую уточняющую правку, чтобы не было разночтений по этому вопросу ;-)

Comment: Ну, дробить логику на малюсенькие функции и импортировать малюсенькие функции как отдельные модули - это разные вещи же. В статье говорится о проблеме, что девелоперу проще добавить зависимость, чем руками написать функцию. Но в итоге, что так,  что так - код будет в отдельной функции, либо в том же вашем коде, либо в зависимом пакете

Comment: В смысле, SRP приводит к большому количеству маленьких классов и маленьких функций, а как они будут рассредоточены по пакетам - это уже SRP не решает. Я потому и не понял связи